# After target reconciliation, "Reconciliation Update Received" task is not getting added to user resource history

Tags: active-directory, identity-management, oim

We have Active Directory connector(11.1.1.6.0 ) on OIM11gR2PS3 box.

When we do the AD target recon the user resource profile is getting updated successfully with target values, but the "Reconciliation Update Received" task is not getting generated in the resource history.

This is intermittent issue causing for some users only.

Any one know why it's behaving like that?